# Laravel - $app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing') method does not work

Tags: php, laravel

so I am trying to load my env into unit tests to avoid defining api keys in the phpunit.xml file in Laravel 5.8. Here is my issue:

```
   public function createApplication()
{
    $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
    if (file_exists(dirname(__DIR__) . '/.env.testing')) {
        (new \Dotenv\Dotenv(dirname(__DIR__), '.env.testing'))->load();
    }

    $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

    return $app;
}
```

The above works and the env vars all get loaded correctly. However, this is the old way of doing things, all the newer posts recommend doing:

```
       public function createApplication()
{
    $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
    $app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing');    
    $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();
    return $app;
}
```

Does anyone have any clue as to why the "suggested" way of loading the env does not work? $app->environmentFilePath() shows the env is being loaded from the correct location.

Comment: See this bug: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12944#issuecomment-214751735

Answer (score 0):

For unit testing purpose, Laravel already transparently handles existing `.env.testing` file.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/testing#environment